# listview toggle button click to stop alarmManager of different class

Tags: android, listview, togglebutton, getview

So i have a listview in my main activity that contains a toggle button
i want to initialize and use toggle button 
what i know is that i should initialise it in my getView..not in my onCreate since its in the listview
but whether i set it in onCreate or getView i get a null pointer exception pointing to my line  toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {.. what am i doing wrong

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(row==null || row.getTag()==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResource,null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();

            holder.mTitle=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.mDate=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
            holder.mTime=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.timeText);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }



        holder.myAlarm = getItem(position);
        holder.mTitle.setText(holder.myAlarm.getTitle());
        holder.mDate.setText(holder.myAlarm.getMonth()+" "+holder.myAlarm.getDay()+", "+holder.myAlarm.getYear());

        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IT IS CHECKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IT IS NOT CHECKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

 return row;
 }
```

any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does Your toggle button include on each row of listview? if that instead of using this

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
```

use this

```
holder.toggle = (ToggleButton) row.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
```